# Will Three Manovas be appropriate?

Tags: manova

I’m running a correlations analysis. Hypothesis is that group 1 will score higher in subscale measures of socioemotional dimensions. Dependent variables- three different learning style groups(smallest group is group 1). independent variables= 3 subscale scores in one measure; 4 sub scale scores in another measure and 6 sub scale scores in the final measure. I intend to run three Manovas, to keep N less than number of outcome measures.

Comment: I would run a RM ANOVA instead assuming there's sphericity if not, estimate using mixed model/GEE.

Comment: you didn't mention you had time dependent data, regular ANOVA sounds perfect otherwise.

Comment: Forgot to say that group one has N=6